# OneToManyField relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a OneToManyField relationship in Django? There is a ManyToOneField relationship but that restrict you declare the relationship on the Many side.

Comment: Why do you care where the declaration is done? You can access it from both sides.

Comment: for the admin site.

Comment: With admin-inlines you can include them in either admin-modelsite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should recognise that Django fields represent database columns. A ForeignKey field is exactly that, a field on the model that represents a key in another model. But you can't model a "one-to-many" field in that way; what would the field on the model represent? So no, it is not possible.

Comment: Why couldn't django make it so when you define a OneToManyField, a link table is created (like it does for ManyToMany) where the column representing the 'One' key on the link table is unique? Would that be poor practice?

Comment: Is there a simple workaround for this? eg, you have a Project model that has foreign keys to a couple of other tables, fine, all data in all of these tables is easily accessible. Now suppose you add an Updates model that uses a Foreign key from the Project model (giving a column in Updates table that references what project it belongs to)  and that Update model has a child table, in this case category, so splitting the updates by category, it is not possible to directly access the Updates per Project per Category, because the Foreign key is going in the wrong direction.